# How to fill blank cells by theirs next avaiable values in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I have some blank cells in Excel like Figure 1. I want to fill those blank cells like Figure 2. I mean, I want to fill the blank cells by the next non-blank value.

I want to do it with a single command as I have high volume of data. Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ecology,

In MS Excel you can automatically fill data in adjacent cells using the "Fill Command".
Please take a look at: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Fill-data-automatically-in-worksheet-cells-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db

You can also do this using VBA.
http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/771-excel-fill-blank-cells-with-value-above.html

Comment: Oh woah, that's good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a "general" macro I use to copy data down a column, which I have tweaked for you, since you want to copy *up*.  Here's a solution in VBA:

```
Sub GEN_USE_Copy_Data_Up_Column()
Dim screenRefresh As String, runAgain As String
Dim lastRow As Long, newLastRow As Long
Dim CopyFrom As Range
Dim LastRowCounter As String

screenRefresh = MsgBox("Turn OFF screen updating while macro runs?", vbYesNo)
If screenRefresh = vbYes Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Else
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If

Dim EffectiveDateCol As Integer
LastRowCounter = InputBox("What column has the most data (this info will be used to find the last used row). Use Letters")

CopyAgain:
With ActiveSheet
    'lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastRowCounter).End(xlUp).row
    lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
End With


' THIS WILL ASK THE USER TO SELECT THE COLUMN TO COPY DATA DOWN
MsgBox ("Now, you will choose a column, and that column's data will be pasted in the range below the current cell, to the next full cell")
Dim Column2Copy As String
Column2Copy = InputBox("What column (A,B,C, etc.) would you like to copy the data of?")

Dim startCell As Range
Set startCell = Cells(1048576, Column2Copy).End(xlUp)

'Cells(1, Column2Copy).End(xlDown).Select
Do While startCell.Row > 1
    If startCell.End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
        newLastRow = 1
        Else
        newLastRow = startCell.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End If
    Set CopyFrom = startCell
    If startCell.Row Mod 5 = 0 Then Debug.Print startCell.Row
    Range(Cells(startCell.Row, Column2Copy), Cells(newLastRow, Column2Copy)).Value = CopyFrom.Value
    Set startCell = startCell.End(xlUp)
    'startCell.Select
Loop

runAgain = MsgBox("Would you like to run the macro on another column?", vbYesNo)
If runAgain = vbNo Then
Cells(1, 1).Select
If screenRefresh = vbYes Then
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Else
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If

Exit Sub

ElseIf runAgain = vbYes Then
GoTo CopyAgain
End If

End Sub
```

Since it's a "general use" macro, I have prompts asking you which column to copy and if you want screen updating on.  If you don't need these, let me know and I can remove/cut out some of the "fluff" and leave the main portion of the macro.

Comment: Thanks BruceWayne. It's working